# How can I ensure the New Relic agent is fully connected in my .NET Core app without using a sleep?

Tags: c#, .net-core, newrelic

I'm integrating New Relic into my .NET Core application. However, I've encountered a scenario where the service needs to wait until the New Relic agent is fully connected before proceeding. Currently, I'm using a static 3-second sleep to ensure the agent is ready and all logs are available in New Relic.

Below is my Program.cs:

```
private static void InitNewRelic()
{
    var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    var newRelicSettings = new NewRelicSettings("my-app-webjob", version, "NewRelic");
    NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.RecordCustomEvent(newRelicSettings.EventType, new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Version", newRelicSettings.Version)
    });
    Target.Register<NewRelicTarget>(newRelicSettings.TargetName);
    WaitUntilNewRelicAgentIsFullyConnected();
}

private static void WaitUntilNewRelicAgentIsFullyConnected()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to handle this without adding a sleep? I want to ensure that the New Relic agent is fully connected before proceeding with the application logic.

Comment: What is the `Target.Register()` method? Is it some sort of wrapper of yours around the New Relic API?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Hi, it's a Nlog method => NLog.Targets

Comment: So `RecordCustomEvent()` is initiating the connection which you are waiting for to be fully established?

Comment: No, the newrelic agent is configured in my machine and it's attached to the application with a newrelic.config, InitNewRelic() is a initial configuration.

Comment: Have you had a look at [`NewRelic.StartAgent()`](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/net-agent/net-agent-api/start-agent/) already? It says it can enforce a blocking startup of the agent at the end.